# Progress как background.

Tags: css3, html5, background, progress-bar

Никак не получается сделать progress-bar background'ом div'а.

```
<div id="values">
  <span></span>
  <!-- some elements -->
  <progress val="10" max="100"></progress>
</div>
```

Пробовал установить значения :

```
#values > progress{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:-1;
}
#values{
  background: none; 
}
#values > * :not(progress){
  position: absolute; 
  /*если получиться избавиться от absolute, то это будет лучше*/
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Но ничего не получалось, как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать градиент:

```js
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    var percent = 50 // - процент заполнения
    element.setAttribute("style","background: linear-gradient(90deg,skyblue 0%,skyblue "+percent+"%,#fff "+percent+"%,#fff 100%);");
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;padding: 5px;">
Текст
</div>
```

Возможно это не совсем то,но я так понимаю,ваша цель - это сделать progressbar задним фоном

Comment: Имитация progressbar'а тоже подойдет, ваша реализация даже проще моей. Только зачем в градиенте вы указали `#fff 39%`?

Comment: Извиняюсь,это значило переход из начала в середину градиента,но тут он не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью css решить данную проблему я не смог, пришлось воспользоваться js и jquery

```
function setBackground(id){
    let width = $(`#${id}`).outerWidth();
    let height = $(`#${id}`).outerHeight();
    let border = parseInt($(`#${id}`).css("border-width"),10);
    let pos = $(`#${id}`).offset();
    for(let i in pos){
        pos[i] += border;
    }
    width -= 2*border;
    height-= 2*border;
    $(`#${id}`)
        .children()
        .css("position","relative")
        .css("z-index",3);
    $(`#${id} > progress`)
        .width(width)
        .height(height)
        .css("position","absolute")
        .css("z-index",0)
        .offset(pos);
}
```